# It took five years for the problem to resolve vs. It took five years for the problem to be resolved

Tags: word-usage

Can ***resolve*** be used as an intransitive verb? Then the two sentences are both correct. But I couldn't find any item in dictionaries that describes the word as an intransitive verb in the same meaning as a transitive one.

Comment: If you mean *resolved* in the sense of *solve*, it is only transitive. However I believe I have come across *resolve* used in the sense of *become clear*, though I haven't found any references. In some contexts this would have a similar meaning to the *solve* meaning.

Comment: Yes https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "resolve" can function as both a transitive and intransitive verb, depending on its usage in a sentence. However, with this particular usage, I think you're confusing the object of a transitive verb with the *agent* of the verb.

In your example of "*it took five years for the problem *to be* resolved*" there is an *implied agent*, because the auxiliary verb *to be* indicates that the verb was carried out by someone.

"*It took five years for the problem to resolve*" sounds wrong. There is no agent, implied or otherwise. Of course, you don't always need to state who, or how something *was resolved* but when you use the infinitive form of the verb it doesn't sound right. The infinitive indicates the purpose or result of the action expressed by the main verb 'took' and it just doesn't sound right without either confirming whose time it took, or if the problem just 'resolved itself'.

You should say something like:

- It took five years *to resolve* the problem.
- It took five years for the problem to resolve *itself*.

Comment: "for the problem to resolve" doesn't strike my AmE ear as bad or marginal, although the reflexive sounds fine too. Here's both: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for+the+problem+to+resolve%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=224fa05bca59979e&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0-Fe0OViFfZhVLNXFJgTzmgNsY__A:1709901710466&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMirag2OSEAxXDhIkEHVS2AgEQpwV6BAgBEBQ&biw=1356&bih=681&dpr=1